# well-definedness of closed set in Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $\mathfrak{p} \subset$ Spec($A$).

Then for an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$, we have a closed set in the Zariski topology defined by

$V(\mathfrak{a})$:={$\mathfrak{p} \in$ Spec($A$) | $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p}$} $\subset$ Spec($A$).

My question is, why do we allow  that $V(\mathfrak{a})= \emptyset$? As there is no empty prime ideal the inclusion $\emptyset = V(\mathfrak{a}) \subset$ Spec($A$) does not make sense to me.

Comment: If you take $\mathfrak{a}=A,$ then $V(\mathfrak{a})=\emptyset$ because, by definition, prime ideals are proper and so there is no prime ideal containing the whole ring. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!:)  but what still confuses me is, why is $\emptyset \subset$ Spec($A$)?

Comment: No problem :) As to your second question: the empty set is a *subset* of any set but it's not necessarily an element of the set. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes very much, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)